# Enforce type check with optional argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, rust, types, error-handling

Following this [article](https://www.huy.rocks/everyday/02-14-2022-typescript-implement-rust-style-result), I'm trying to mimic Rust's `Result<T,E>` type in TypeScript, this is the code:

```
type Result<T, E> =
  | { ok: true; data: T }
  | { ok: false; error: E };

const Ok = <T>(data: T): Result<T, never> => {
  return { ok: true, data };
};

const Err = <E>(error: E): Result<never, E> => {
  return { ok: false, error };
};
```

I want to make it a bit better, so that the `Ok()` argument could be optional if the `T` type is `undefined`, but if I make it optional, all the other types do not enforce argument to be present.

E.g. If I change `data: T` argument of `Ok()` to be `data?: T`, I can use `Ok()` with no value.

```
function testFunc(isOk: boolean): Result<undefined, Error> {
  if (isOk) {
    return Ok();
  }

  return Err(new Error("my error"));
}
```

But I can't enforce other type:

```
function testFunc(isOk: boolean): Result<number, Error> {
  if (isOk) {
    // --- Gives me an error (string is not assignable to number)
    return Ok('hi');
    // --- Doesn't give me an error, but I need it
    return Ok();
  }

  return Err(new Error("my error"));
}
```

**Is it even possible to do something like this, considering I want to only use these two functions `Ok` and `Err` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
function Ok<T>(): Result<T | undefined, never>;
function Ok<T>(data: T): Result<T, never>;
function Ok<T>(data?: T): Result<T | undefined, never> {
  return { ok: true, data };
}
```